# Facebook iOS SDK / FBSDKLoginButton ignoring read permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

I'm trying to initialize a Facebook Login button (FBSDKLoginButton) using the following read permissions:

- user_hometown
- public_profile
- email
- user_about_me

Is this too much to be asking? I see the array values set correctly in my button instance but when I attempt to authorize, the auth view that appears only shows the following permissions requested:

[image]

Here's my init code:

```
if( _loginButton == nil ) {
    //  Initialize the FBSDKLoginButton and add to contentView
    _loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    _loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"user_hometown", @"public_profile", @"email", @"user_about_me"];
    _loginButton.delegate = self;
    [[self contentView] addSubview:_loginButton];
}
```

If it's not too intrusive to ask for these permissions, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the user_location permission to access location info like user_hometown.

Both will require review by facebook to be used for non-testers/developers.

Comment: Hrm, nope, adding that didn't help.